# Add SF CLI to GitHub Actions Cache

Tags: salesforcedx, cli, github-actions

I'm trying to cache sf cli in GitHub Actions but I get `sf: command not found` when the cache is restored. Does anyone know which other paths I need to add to the cache?

```
- name: Cache
  id: cache
  uses: actions/cache@v3
  with:
    path: |
      ~/.npm
      node_modules
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}

- name: Setup Node
  if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
  uses: actions/setup-node@v4
  with:
    node-version: ">=20"

- name: Install Salesforce CLI & Plugins
  if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
  shell: bash
  run: |
    sudo npm install @salesforce/cli --global
    echo y | sf plugins install sfdx-git-delta
    sf --version
    sf plugins --core

- name: Install Dependencies
  if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
  shell: bash
  run: npm ci
```